# Change UIITabbar width ios13 swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar, ios13

I had this piece of code which worked perfectly prior to ios13 :

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

     var newFrame = tabBar.frame
     newFrame.size.width = self.view.bounds.width - 420
     tabBar.frame = newFrame

 }
```

but now it does nothing on ios13 running ipad.
I have also tried using an `extention` and creating my own `CustomTabBar` and change the width from `sizeThatFits()` method, but this method `ONLY CHANGES THE HEIGHT` and when trying to change the width of the tabbar it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

     var newFrame = tabBar.frame
     newFrame.size.width = self.view.bounds.width - 420
     tabBar.frame = newFrame

 }
```

this works in Objective-C like so, just tested it:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  CGRect newFrame = self.tabBar.frame;
  newFrame.size.width -= 200;
  self.tabBar.frame = newFrame;

}
```

should work the same in Swift, although i have no idea why in the world you would ever want to do this and it won't do anything other than shift the tabbar buttons to the left